# React Native iOS "Expected function body after function declaration" in RCTLog.m

Tags: ios, react-native

I started receiving this error (Expected function body after function declaration) unexpectedly. I didn't do any changes with my code or smth.

[image]

Do you have any ideas why is it happening?

Comment: Remove first slash character from the first line :)

Comment: oh, thank you very much! You saved my day!:)

Comment: @halilb Add that as an answer so this question is answered :)

Comment: Thanks @MartinKonicek, i just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/** */` is a proper comment block in Objective-C. You've unintentionally added extra `/` characters in the opening comment block line and that's why the compiler can't compile the file properly.